# Does Laravel Framework need these files I mentioned below to run properly ? Is Laravel dependent on these files?

Tags: laravel

I don't know if this question is valid, but I have a lot of findings on my application when scanned by checkmarx, all files related to findings is part of the laravel framework installation package,

This includes files such as

```
/vendor/sebastian/comparator/src/DOMNodeComparator.php
/vendor/sebastian/comparator/src/ArrayComparator.php
/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Tests/RequestTest.php
/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php
```

I want to know if these files are vital to the Laravel App? is the Laravel framework dependent on these files above? Is it being used by Laravel by default?

Thank You,

Comment: any explanation for down voting?? it's better to comment first before down voting, down voting without a comment is much worst than asking a shitty question, It would not resolve anything either,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `sebastian/comparator` is used by `phpunit/phpunit` to do testing. It's not needed when you do not need to do unit testing (production code).
- `RequestTest.php` is only used for unit testing on `Request.php`
- `http-foundation/Request.php` yes, vital. It's the base class of all http request related calls.

---

You can do a `composer show --tree` to print a dependency tree, to know what's vital to the core framework.

Comment: does it mean I can remove those files? I'm not using any unit testing will it be ok if I delete those unused files?  thanks again

Comment: Actually why do you need to remove them? Any particular reason? If you run it on production, you can do `composer install --no-dev` to omit all the development dependencies, that will remove phpunit from your vendor files.